# Google OAuth 2.0 Authentication in a C# Installed Application

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to add OAuth authentication to a C# program that works with Gmail using IMAP.  The actual AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command in IMAP is working perfectly if I obtain an Access Token from the OAuth 2.0 Playground.  However my attempts to enable the program to obtain an Access Token itself are stalled.  I have read the RFCs and have a bit of an idea of what is going on but am still struggling to make practical sense of it all.  So I am asking for help.

The code I am failing with is as follows, copied from a sample [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2#Installed_Applications):

```
ClientSecrets clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets{ClientId = myClientID, ClientSecret = myClientSecret};

string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://mail.google.com" };

Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                clientSecrets, scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

When I run this, I receive an error message in my browser saying:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:59904/authorize/ did not match a registered redirect URI
```

I understand that I need to set a redirect URI of "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" but I am at a loss to figure out how to do this and to understand why the sample fails to do so.

Many thanks for any assistance...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a web application's client secrets and NOT installed application's client secrets.

You should verify in the cloud console that you are using Installed Application. Then, you won't have any problem, cause installed application doesn't need to register any URI.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I had wondered why the json I downloaded had "web" in it instead of "installed".  I must have completely missed where I should have specified installed application.  Thank you again.